# Update query giving exception in Java using SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

```
PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE employee SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, HighestDegreeEarned = ?, JoiningDate = ?, CurrentPost = ?, DeparmentID = ?, ContactNo(Mobile) = ?, ContactNo(Home) = ?, CurrentAddress = ?, PermanentAddress = ? WHERE ID =  ?");

update.setString(1, firstnametxt.getText());
update.setString(2, lastnametxt.getText());
update.setString(3, degreetxt.getText());
update.setString(4, joiningdatetxt.getText());
update.setString(5, currentposttxt.getText());
update.setString(6, departmentidtxt.getText());
update.setString(7, mobiletxt.getText());
update.setString(8, contactnotxt.getText());
update.setString(9, currentaddresstxt.getText());
update.setString(10, permanentaddresstxt.getText());
update.setString(11, empidtxt.getText());

update.executeUpdate();
```

here is the code and on exexuting i m getting the error below.
SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.kindly help me

Comment: Are the statements `ContactNo(Mobile)` and `ContactNo(Home)` acceptable in SQL Server? It seems just like what the driver is complaining about.

Comment: @Filipe Fedalto: You should write that as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column in database can't be named: ContactNo(Mobile) or ContactNo(Home)

If ContactNo() is a function, use dynamic sql to call out it.

Comment: actually, you CAN use ContantNo(Mobile) as column name in MSSQL, but such names must be treated as delimited identifiers (quoted or bracketed). e.g. for bracketed identifiers - surround them with square brackets - [ContactNo(Mobile)]. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033%28v=sql.80%29.aspx however such naming is rather discouraged in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons for failing

1. ContactNo function in SQL server does not exit or not compiled
2. JoiningDate format is incorrect

Comment: Ad 1) It can't be function... Function can't be used in set (in update statement) as column name (only in dynamic sql it's possbile)
Ad 2) It can't be date format because error is: "Incorrect syntax near ')'."